# Docker and HMR sync

Tags: javascript, docker, webpack, hot-module-replacement, laradock

I have both laravel and with integrated react build with Docker(Laradock). I am trying to use Hot module reload (HMR), and sync files in that way. Is this thing event possible.

First trying to resolve this issue with base url, because getting this error.

```
http://localhost:8080//js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

produced in this line

```
 <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

then my idea is to run

```
sudo docker-compose exec workspace bash
```

and run from there

```
npm run hot
```

Can you help me to resolve mix() url error and is my logic correct for running npm hot run from workspace?

Comment: stil no answers?

Comment: whats going on, in need clarification